# A good host that supports windows 2008 & PostgreSQL?

Tags: web-hosting

Looking for a good host for a project on Win2008 and PostgreSQL.
I found these 2 sites but they support older versions of PostgreSQL.

[http://www.jodohost.com/](http://www.jodohost.com/windows.asp)
http://www.gbehost.com/

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the best Windows hosts out there: http://www.arvixe.com/

Comment: They only support postgresql on Linux.